# SQL on a VM. Backup to Network location or just backup to VM

Tags: sql-server

I'm used to working with physical servers so interested in your thoughts/experience on this.

I'm now working in a VM environment and wondering how you guys handle SQL backups?  I understand best practice is to backup to a network share when using physical devices, but does this still apply to VM's?  VM's obviously use shared storage so not sure of the point of backing up to a network share.

Anyone any thoughts on this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should still backup away from the VM, or at least copy the backups off, preferably to a redundant location (either another SAN, or tape, whatever).

VMs can come back from a lot of things, but if you suffer a catastrophic failure, you may not be able to access the VM storage easily.

- C: drive fills up
- Windows dies a horrible death
- A patch goes wrong at some level (VM, Windows, etc.)

Backing up to a VM-agnostic location gives you some breathing room. While the SAN may still be a single point of failure (remember the redundant location thing?), if you need to stand up a new VM in an emergency, you want the backups to be as easy to restore as possible.

Comment: Thanks Erik for coming back to me so quickly!  Makes sense. Probably the best option is to backup to the VM Virtual drive and also a network share at the same time then?  The company use Zerto for DR.  Have you any experience using this tool?

Comment: It would be inappropriate for me to comment on vendor tool experience in this case. I'd just say: be very careful that you're not taking dirty snaps.

Comment: ah ok!  Totally understand.  Thanks for your help. :-)

Comment: Erik. Our infrastructure guys have just come back saying they would prefer us to backup to a network share instead of adding a new drive to the VM. I had planned to do both, ie add a new drive, backup to there and then copy backups to network share.  Their reasoning is adding another drive to VM will make VM backups more costly. Is there any issue just (and only) backing up to network share instead of VM.

Comment: Nope. Definitely keep an eye on how long VM snaps freeze data for though. Look for frozen I/O messages in the error log.

Comment: Thanks Erik. Will keep an eye on the logs. Thanks for coming back to me so quickly.